# Combining ordinal scales where each level is numerical range

Tags: ordinal-data, composite

I am working with a dataset that has several variables querying time spent using media each day. Each variable queries a different type of media use, with the same answer options. An example question is, "how much time did you spend today talking on your phone?" The answer options are:

a) < 30 Min
b) 30 Min - 1 Hr
c) 1 - 2 Hrs
d) 2 - 3 Hrs
e) 3+ Hrs

There are 7 questions in total.

I would like to create a composite of these 7 ordinal variables. My idea was to take the midpoint of each answer and create an average. For example, if someone answered A, D, E, B, C, A, then D, that would translate to 0.25 hours, 2.5 hours, 3 hours, 0.75 hours, 1.5 hours, 0.25 hours, and 2.5 hours, with the average being 1.54 hours spent on media use per day.

Is this considered an "appropriate" way to combine the variables? If not, is there a more appropriate way?

Comment: Although measuring a different phenomenon, the open-ended upper tail in midpoint-based estimates of ordinal income categories bears some resemblance to your problem: Angle, J. (2004). The Salamander: A Model of the Right Tail of the Wage Distribution Truncated by Topcoding [Working Paper]. Economic Research Service.

Comment: Wanted to bump my post to see if there are any solutions